# How can I plot dates on X axis in mplwidget of pyqtgraph

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtwidgets

I am trying to plot a graph in my ui created by pyqt5. I want to plot dates in X axis and corresponding value in dataframe on y axis. My dataframe has a column as dates and other column has values corresponding each dates.

```
x_values = data["Dates"]
y_values = np.array(data["Capital Charge"])

self.MplWidget.plot(x_values, y_values)
self.MplWidget.setTitle("Capital Charge for last 6 months of "+selected_entity)
self.MplWidget.setLabel('left', 'Capital Charge', color='red', size=40)
self.MplWidget.setLabel('bottom', 'COB Dates', color='red', size=40)
```

but this doesn't work out. Please help me out in case you have any idea.
Thank you

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: pyqtgraph and matplotlib are two completely separate things, so I think you'll have more luck tagging your post with "matplotlib" and removing pyqtgraph from the title.